# VBA - copy values sheet1 -> sheet2, A505:A700 > E2:E197 but stop if cell goes blank

Tags: vba, copy

The action is already in the title and I know I'm close but got stuck:

```
Dim wsS As Worksheet, wsU As Worksheet
Set wsS = Sheets("sheet1")
Set wsU = Sheets("non_confid")
Dim col1 As String, col2 As String, i As Long, j As Long
Set wsS = ActiveWindow.ActiveSheet
col1 = "A"
Set wsU = ActiveWindow.ActiveSheet
col2 = "E"
For i = 505 To 700
For j = 2 To 197
    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
       wsS.Range(col1 & i).Copy
       wsU.Range(col2 & j).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
Next i
```

*the list is already sorted so it will end by the first blank cell
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thank you so much - Found the problem:
For i = 505 To 700
For j = 2 To 197
becomes
For i = 505 To 700 And j = i-503

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code seems to have quite a few anomolies. I'll refactor it a little below

```
Dim wsS As Worksheet
Dim wsU As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

Set wsS = Sheets("sheet1") 'this has assigned the worksheet sheet1 to wsS
Set wsU = Sheets("non_confid") 'this has assigned the worksheet sheet1 to wsU

col1 = "A"
col2 = "E"

For i = 505 To 700
       If Not IsEmpty(wsS.Range(col1 & i).Value) Then
            wsU.Range(col2 & i - 503).Value = wsS.Range(col1 & i).Value
       End If

Next
```

That behaves similarly to your code, but should copy correctly. I'm not sure from your question whether you want it simply to skip empty values, or stop executing. To skip empty values in the range, the following version of the code will work.

```
Dim wsS As Worksheet
Dim wsU As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Set wsS = Sheets("sheet1") 'this has assigned the worksheet sheet1 to wsS
Set wsU = Sheets("non_confid") 'this has assigned the worksheet sheet1 to wsU

col1 = "A"
col2 = "E"
j = 2

For i = 505 To 700
       If Not IsEmpty(wsS.Range(col1 & i).Value) Then
            wsU.Range(col2 & j).Value = wsS.Range(col1 & i).Value
            j = j + 1 'here is a new counter for the position on the second page.
       End If

Next
```

if you want the loop to stop on finding an empty cell, then the following code should work.

```
Dim wsS As Worksheet
Dim wsU As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Set wsS = Sheets("sheet1") 'this has assigned the worksheet sheet1 to wsS
Set wsU = Sheets("non_confid") 'this has assigned the worksheet sheet1 to wsU

col1 = "A"
col2 = "E"
j = 2

For i = 505 To 700
       If IsEmpty(wsS.Range(col1 & i).Value) Then
            Exit For 'this jumps out of the loop, so no more copying.
       Else
            wsU.Range(col2 & j).Value = wsS.Range(col1 & i).Value
            j = j + 1
       End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use something like this:

```
    Sub kamal()

    Dim wsS As Worksheet, wsU As Worksheet
    Set wsS = Sheets("sheet1")
    Set wsU = Sheets("non_confid")

    For j = 2 To 197

    If Len(Trim(wsS.Range(A & j + 503).Value)) > 0 Then

     wsU.Range(col2 & j).Value = wsS.Range(col1 & j + 503).Value

    End If

    Next

    End Sub
```

Or an easy ways is using formulas.

Comment: "Compile error:

Invalid Next control variable reference" - just like before (and it selects "i" from the line "Next i"